# Terminating bidirectional data lines and clock for memory-mapped devices

Tags: termination, sram

I am wiring up an STM32H743 to an SRAM or an FPGA to memory map it (i.e. I would like to be able to re-use the schematic). This SRAM operates at a maximum of 50MHz. The FPGA can operate at 50MHz all the way up to 200MHz, I believe.

It would be nice if I could run the bus to both SRAM and FPGA on the same PCB and only populate one as required (or populate both but only activate one as required) but I am not sure that would be feasible as far as signal integrity goes; mainly because I don't know how you can terminate bidirectional lines that drop off at taps along the way, even if the taps are stubless since some of the taps in the middle of the line end up being drivers.

I had some trepidations about the general approach to memory terminations. Can anyone confirm that how I have gone about things is generally okay?

Namely:

1. Series termination on the driver end for the unidirectional address lines.
2. Series termination on both ends end for the bidirectional data lines.
3. Parallel termination a little past the "tap" for the receiver for the clock.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what 3 means but definitely double series on bidirectional lines.

Comment: @Andyaka 3 just means a parallel termination at the receiver. Except instead of being just before the receiver, the line "drops off" onto the receiver and travels past it a bit almost as if it was daisy chaining to something else, and then terminates. Just so that the end termination truly is at the end of the bus instead of shortly before it.

Answer (score 1):

I've only done external SDRAM on NXP LPC54648 which can go up to 100Mhz on the external memory interface.  On their eval board they only used series termination on the eval board.  So when I did my board, I stuck with that.
With the cpu and ram about 1.5cm apart, it works great.

<s>For your double termination (data lines) I would recommend using half the resistor value as you do for the single terminations (address lines).</s>

From Dr. Howard Johnsons web site:
[Bi-Directional Termination](http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/2_20.htm)

> [XCVR  A]--[resistor B]--[C--long line--D]--[resistor E]--[XCVR F]
>   From transceiver A, the signal passes first through series terminating
>   resistor B, and then to the left end (C) of a long line. The long line
>   runs from C to D.
>
> From the right end (D) of the long line, the signal goes through
>   another series terminating resistor E, and from there into transceiver
>   F.
>
> Resistor B, plus the natural output impedance of driver A when it is
>   engaged and transmitting, should equal the Z0 of the line.
>
> Resistor E, plus the natural output impedance of driver F when it is
>   engaged and transmitting, should equal the Z0 of the line.
>
> When driver A is working, driver F should be in the tri-state
>   (open-circuited) condition. This provides a normal series-terminated
>   configuration when A is driving.
>
> When driver F is working, driver A should be in the tri-state
>   (open-circuited) condition. Now the line is source-terminated at F.
>
> The only peculiar thing you will notice about this setup is that the
>   rise time at the receiving device may be somewhat degraded, and a
>   little delayed, from the normal situation you would expect in a series
>   terminated line. This is due to the effect of the idle (unused) series
>   terminator at each end of the line. The received signal has to go
>   through this extra resistor into the receiver. In the process of doing
>   so, we get an R-C lowpass filter effect with a time constant equal to:
>
> T(Bidirectional,0-63) = (Z0+Rs)*Cout
>
> Where: 
>   Z0 is the line impedance, 
>   Rs is the value of series terminator,
>   and Cout is the output capacitance of the transceiver when in the
>   tri-state (off) condition.

Comment: I am a bit unsure if it's supposed to be double or half the resistor. My understanding is that it's a tradeoff between rise time at the receiver end and dampening of reflections at the source. The series resistance on the receiver side gets overwhelmed by the high receiver input impedance but does serve to slow the rise time a bit due to the parasitic C.

Comment: @DKNguyen You are correct.  See my updated answer.